# Nested Marshmallow field does not show data in nested Schema

Tags: python, api, flask, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I have a table type and language. I have a 1 to many relationship called languages from Type to Language. Marshmallow keeps showing there is no data inside a Type entry despite the data showing up in the console. Does anyone have any idea why?

schemas.py

```
class LanguageSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Language
        ordered = True

    language = ma.auto_field()
    

class TypeSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Type
        ordered = True

    id = ma.auto_field(dump_only=True)
    name = ma.auto_field(required=True, validate=validate.Length(min=3, max=64))
    settings = ma.Nested(TypeSettingsSchema, dump_only=True)
    languages = ma.Nested(LanguageSchema, many=False)
```

models.py

```
class Language(Updateable, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'language'

    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    language = sqla.Column(sqla.String(2), nullable=False)

    type_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey(Type.id), index=True)
    type = sqla_orm.relationship('Type', back_populates='languages')

class Type(Updateable, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'type'

    languages = sqla_orm.relationship('Language', back_populates='type')
```

Output from query

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "languages": {},
      "name": "Grocery",
      "settings": {
        "isHome": true,
        "layoutType": "classic",
        "productCard": "neon"
      }
    }]
}
```

console output showing what the query for id1 brings up and you can clearly see languages has data.

```
>>> t1.id
1
>>> t1.languages[0].language
'en'
>>> t1.name
'Grocery'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a one to many relationship from type to language. So set the `many` parameter for the nested `languages` attribute within the TypeSchema to `True` and it should work.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class Language(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False)

    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('type.id'))
    type = db.relationship('Type', backref='languages')

class Type(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

class LanguageSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Language

class TypeSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Type
    languages = ma.Nested(LanguageSchema, only=('code',), many=True)

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    l = Language(code='en')
    t = Type(
        name='Grocery',
        languages=[l]
    )

    db.session.add(t)
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    types = Type.query.all()
    types_schema = TypeSchema(many=True)
    types_data = types_schema.dump(types)
    return jsonify(data=types_data)
```

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "languages": [
        {
          "code": "en"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Grocery"
    }
  ]
}
```